# Dangerous Power Supply

Tags: power-supply, dc

I recently bought a 3D printer from the USA and imported it to the UK, it came with a Chinese 12v DC 30 Amp power regulator. The PSU is a metal enclosed box. It can take 220 Volts +/-15% so it should be okay to run on the uk mains. It has three input terminals live, neutral and an earth terminal. There are four DC 12 volt outputs and four zero volt terminals.

The unit is a YGY 123000 12V DC rack mounted power supply. The only place I can find selling these units is a shop in Lebanon.

I did some checks with an ohm meter. These checks revaled that the earth was not connected to the metal chassi. The earth terminal is connected to the 0V DC output terminals.

I don't dare connect this PSU to the mains and I have since ordered a quality PSU a COPEK AK-350-12 at great expense.

Have I done the right thing and what should I tell the manufacturer of the 3D printer?

Comment: What exactly are you objecting to about this power supply?

Comment: The fact it's metal and it isn't earthed. Also that the mains supply isn't isolated from the DC output. I could earth the case myself easily. I can't find a data sheet on this unit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a good chance that there isn't anything wrong with the power supply.  But it will require more investigation on your part.

1) The AC Mains input terminals L & N should NOT be connected to any of the output terminals.

2) The Earth terminal is most likely connected to the EMI filter capacitors that provide filtering on the AC Mains terminals.  You need to connect that Earth terminal to your metal chassis and to the Earth lead on the incoming AC Mains cable.  Also note that the metal case of the power supply must also be connected to Earth. That is normally done just by mounting the power supply to your metal chassis.

A little bit of history here: Where I come from (Canada), it is not legal to rely upon a mounting screw to be the only ground connection.  You *can* have a mounting screw that is part of the a ground connection but there must be another ground connection that is not used for mounting something else.

That applies to PC boards as well.  You *can* ground your EMI filter network to the metal power supply enclosure with one of the PCB mounting screws *BUT* that ground connection must not be the only place where the ground connection is located.  The power supply manufacturer must also supply a separate ground terminal.

Which they have done.

Finally, regarding your observation that the power supply 0V DC output is also connected to the Earth terminal: that is just fine.  For example, if you look at the power supply inside most personal computers, you will often find that the 0V DC wires are all connected to Earth.  There isn't anything wrong about this.

Having the 0V DC line connected to Earth may not be what you want and it indeed might cause you problems.  If that is the case, purchase a power supply that is completely floating with respect to Earth.  But it's not a defect if the OV line is in fact connected to Earth.

Comment: It's also possible that the connection of earth to 0V is exactly what you want. A transformer can generate an AC voltage between its secondary side and earth due to capacitive coupling. This voltage can be in the order of 100V, if there's no connection to Earth. The simple solution is a connection to earth as described here. If one needs a really floating output, this connection can be done via a capacitor. Without, you may always get a small shock when touching the electronics, and the interface to the PC may not be stable.

Comment: Thanks for the answer that is just what I needed to know. I have plenty of experience with micro electronics and very little experience with anything over 50 volts. I tested that the live and nuetral were isolated from the outputs. I earthed the case and then plugged it into an rcd. I switched it on and adjusted the volatge to 12 volts DC. No fires or shorts so, so far so good. I can only earth the unit in one place as it's mounted with acyrilc mounting brackets and is therefore isolated from the frame. I will now proceed with the 3D printer wiring whilst it's unplugged of course!

Comment: @JackTaylor: the missing connection between the chassis & the Earth terminal is not a big issue from a user's point of view (it's rather easy to connect them), but it's a big issue from the designer's point of view. And the real question is: if the designer has made such a trivial mistake, what else waits inside that you may not even notice? Once I ordered a Chinese, metal-boxed 12V/2A SMPS (for some ridiculous amount, like $10 or so). When it arrived, I peeked inside, and it looked suspicious. I opened the box, and saw about 0.8mm between the Line input and the Earth terminal...